# Use field of union in intialiser of another variable

Tags: gcc, unions, ansi-c

I am building records for unit testing a software module. Record data is serialised before sending it to the UUT.

The records contain bitfields, so I would like to build serialised records using these same bitfields at compile-time (to prevent having to account for little- and big-endian issues and where the bits in bitfield go) and use a union to access the (serialised) data. I have to calculate a checksum over the record, so I need the bitfields as bytes to do so.

My attempt so far is:

```
/* defines for 64 bit valid record */
#define REC3_ID        EEID_ARRAY_FIRST
#define REC3_SIZE      1
#define REC3_INDEX     248
#define REC3_SI0       MAKE_SIZE_INDEX0(REC3_SIZE,REC3_INDEX)
#define REC3_SI1       MAKE_SIZE_INDEX1(REC3_SIZE,REC3_INDEX)
#define REC3_VALUE0    0xf2
#define REC3_VALUE1    0x4f
#define REC3_VALUE2    0xb8
#define REC3_VALUE3    0xa0
#define REC3_DATA      \
    MAKE_CHKSUM7(REC3_ID,REC3_SI0,REC3_SI1,REC3_VALUE0,REC3_VALUE1,REC3_VALUE2,REC3_VALUE3),\
    REC3_ID,REC3_SI0,REC3_SI1,REC3_VALUE0,REC3_VALUE1,REC3_VALUE2,REC3_VALUE3

#define CHKSUM_SEED (0x2a)
#define MAKE_CHKSUM7(v0,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6) (0x100-(((v0)+(v1)+(v2)+(v3)+(v4)+(v5)+(v6)+CHKSUM_SEED)%0x100))

typedef union
{
    uint8_t si[2];
    struct
    {
        uint16_t s: 6;
        uint16_t i: 10;
    } b;
} si_t;

MAKE_SIZE_INDEX0(size,index) ((si_t){.b.s=size,.b.i=index}).si[0]
MAKE_SIZE_INDEX1(size,index) ((si_t){.b.s=size,.b.i=index}).si[1]

static uint8_t rec3[] = {REC3_DATA};
```

The problem lies with the macros `MAKE_SIZE_INDEX0` and `MAKE_SIZE_INDEX1`. I can't get them to compile (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11))

The problem can be simplified to:

```
uint8_t rec[] = {0x12, (si_t){.b.s=4,.b.i=8}.si[0], (si_t){.b.s=4,.b.i=8}.si[1], 0x34};
```

But that results in error:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

I know I can create my records at run-time, but I wondered whether it is possible to let the preprocessor handle it.

My alternative is something like:

```
#if defined (TGT_ARCHITECTURE_x86_64)
#define MAKE_SIZE_INDEX0(size,index) (((size)&0x3f)+(((index)<<6)&0xc0))
#define MAKE_SIZE_INDEX1(size,index) ((index>>2)&0xff)
#endif
```

But this depends on whether the target is little-endian or big-endian and how it stores bitfields.

Comment: Is `rec` a global variable? Are you aware that compile may do padding between bitfields? `But this depends on whether the target` - no, it's the other way round. Using bit operations will result in the same value independent on the architecture, using union and bit fields is dependend on target endianess and bit order.

Comment: @KamilCuk Why does it matter if `rec` is a global variable? I know that the compiler may add padding; I can handle that by using packed structs or changing the order of fields in my structures. In this case padding doesn't matter, because I want to extract single bytes from a struct initialiser.

Comment: If you need a constant (to initialise something or for any other purpose), write a constant expression. "But this depends on whether the target is little-endian or big-endian" no, it does not. A constant expression cannot possibly depend on endianness. "And how it stores bitfields" It has been said many many times. Do not use bit fields, ever. Use bit masks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static uint8_t rec3[] = { (si_t){.b.s=4,.b.i=8}.si[0] };
```

Variables with static storage duration must be initialized only using a static initializer - it has to be a constant expression. There is a [list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) of what is allowed in a constant expression - using [array subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) on a array embedded in a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) is not allowed in a constant expression. It's basically the same as you can't do `static int a[] = {1, 2}; static int b = a[1];`

On a side note, the standard says that implementations are allowed to accept custom forms of constant expression. So the code may happen to work with a different compiler and even a different gcc version (as with newest gcc versions you may initialize variable with static storage duration with const qualived variable, which is an extension).

The compiler errors with "initializer element is not constant", as the element used to initialize variable with static storage duration is not a constant expression.

Using bit-fields to extract a bit-mask of a variable is compiler dependent, compiler options dependent ([gcc storage layout](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Storage-Layout.html)) and shouldn't be used in portable code. Compiler is free to reorder the bitfields in your struct and is free to add padding between bit fields members. As advertised on stackoverflow many, many times, use bitmasks - they work every time.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried, but my compiler returns `error: initializer element is not constant` for this. I am happy with knowing that it is not possible (at least not in a portable way). I am using bitfields in my production code; the attempt to initialise records here was for C unit testing (so it is allowed to be a bit less strict).